# Need to change the color of the parent tag element in spry menu bar followed by current browser URL

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I had tried in many way  like active tag, JavaScript etc.

```
 <ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
   <li><a href="index.php" class="MenuBarItemSubmenu">Home</a>    </li>
   <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">Exam</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="english.php">English</a></li>
      <li><a href="math.php">Math</a></li>
      <li><a href="details.php">Details</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="uklife.php" class="MenuBarItemSubmenu">Uk Life</a>
</ul>
```

When I am in index.php "Home" text color will be different. When in english.php or math.php or detauls.php "Exam" text color will be different an so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last for highlighting current url menu I had got this code. I is working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url=window.location.href;
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.MenuBarItemSubmenu'),elem,desiredElemContents;
    if (url.indexOf('index.php')>-1) 
      desiredElemContents = 'Home';
    else  if(url.indexOf('english.php')>-1||url.indexOf('math.php')>-1 ||url.indexOf('details.php')>-1)
      desiredElemContents = 'Exam';
    else if (url.indexOf('uklife.php')>-1) 
      desiredElemContents = 'Uk Life';
    for(var i=elems.length-1; i>=0; i--) 
      {
        var elemContents = elems[i].textContent || elems[i].innerText;
        if(elemContents!==desiredElemContents) continue;
        elem = elems[i];
        break;
       };
   if (elem) 
    { 
    elem.style.backgroundColor= "#ce0808";
    elem.style.color="white";
    }
</script>
```